# Nested Cursor call is calling inner cursor only once in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, cursor

There are 2 procedures. When tested separately they execute fine.
When first SP calls 2nd SP, this is not called after the first call.
Please help resolve the issue.
First Cursor:

```
    BEGIN
DECLARE vAttendEmpid,vNoOfDays, vempid INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE processed BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE curEmp CURSOR FOR Select distinct empid as d1 from  rawattendance where DATE_FORMAT(     indatetime,'%m') =  process_month and DATE_FORMAT( indatetime,'%Y') = process_year order by     empid;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET processed = TRUE ;

    OPEN curEmp;
    loopemp: LOOP
    FETCH FROM curEmp INTO vEmpid;

        IF processed THEN
            CLOSE curEmp;
            LEAVE loopemp;
        END IF;
        --select vEmpid;
        CALL sp_attendance(vEmpid,process_month,process_year);
    END LOOP loopemp;
END
```

2nd Cursor.. Nested cursor

```
BEGIN
DECLARE  vInDateTime, vOutDateTime,vTempInDateTime, vTempOutDateTime DATETIME ;
DECLARE vAttendEmpid ,vDiffHr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE  eprocessed BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE curAttendance CURSOR FOR Select empid, indatetime ,outdatetime from  rawattendance     where    empid=vEmpid and DATE_FORMAT( indatetime, '%m' ) =  process_month and DATE_FORMAT( indatetime, '%Y' ) = process_year 
    order by indatetime;

    OPEN curAttendance;
    att_loop:LOOP
    FETCH curAttendance INTO vAttendEmpid, vInDateTime,vOutDateTime;

    select concat ('In Time 0 ==',vInDateTime, ' out ==', vOutDateTime, ' Empid=',vAttendEmpid);
            select 'looping';

IF eprocessed THEN
    select 'loop end';
    select concat ('In Time 4 ==',vTempInDateTime, ' out ==', vTempOutDateTime, ' Empid=',vAttendEmpid);
        SET vDiffHr =TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,vTempInDateTime,vTempOutDateTime);

    insert into emp_attendance_processed(empid,in_date_time, out_date_time, workedhr) 
        values(vAttendEmpid,vTempInDateTime,vTempOutDateTime, vDiffHr);
        SET vTempOutDateTime=vOutDateTime;
        CLOSE curAttendance;
    END IF;
END LOOP att_loop;  
END
```

Comment: `process_month` and `process_year` are parameters?

Comment: yes, they r parameters.

Comment: I removed lots of code to check if this works.. but still same issue.. Not being called after first call..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset your continue handler variable `processed` after the inner procedure is called.

```
SET processed = FALSE;
```

The Problem is that the `HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND` is not only executed if the cursor in your first procedure returns no rows, but also if a nested `SELECT` returns no rows. And as your second procedure contains `SELECT` statements, I believe one of them is returning an empty set at least one time. If that's not intended, it may have to do with faulty parameters assigned.

```
OPEN curEmp;
loopemp: LOOP
FETCH FROM curEmp INTO vEmpid;

    IF processed THEN
        CLOSE curEmp;
        LEAVE loopemp;
    END IF;
    --select vEmpid;
    CALL sp_attendance(vEmpid,process_month,process_year);
    SET processed = FALSE;
END LOOP loopemp;
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer towards Handler setting the variable... In the second cursor I changed the LOOP to REPEAT and this solved the problem. I appreciate your suggestions.